# Error Js Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of null

Tags: javascript, compiler-errors

It says this:

> **index.html:50 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null** in function **document.getElementById("bp_infinity").style.display = "block";**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hODMO.png

I really appreciate your answers.

Comment: What's your html look like? If you don't have an element with an id of "bp_infinity" on the page it'll give you this type of error

Comment: Include the code as text, not as a screenshot. As share the relevant HTML.

Comment: Stop posting code inside screenshots!

Answer (score 7):

JS is executing before the DOM is ready..

Either move your `<script>` tag to right before the closing `</body>` tag, or put all your Javascript in an onload function like.. `window.onload = function(){ /** all code goes here **/};`